# Как использовать переменные в discord.py

Tags: python, асинхронность, discord

Хочу сделать бота для мини игры в дискорде, но проблема в том как передавать переменные для команд библиотеки discord.
Например в коде ниже я хочу "заблокировать" команду start после её активации, но т.к сама функция выполняется "вне" программы я не могу сделать проверку за счёт переменной nRound.

Как вообще взаимодействовать с переменами из "вне" в функциях async, если в async функции происходит расчёт, а потом мне нужно эти расчёты сравнить.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

TOKEN = '123'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
nRound = 0

@bot.command(pass_context=False)
async def start(ctx):
    if nRound == 0:
        nRound = 1
        await ctx.send("123")
    else:
        print("Игра началась. Чтобы начать новую игру завершите текущую.")
```

Comment: Ваш пример бота показывает намерение сделать игру для одного человека, т.к. при начале игры одним участником право использования `!start` блокируется для всех. Если вы хотите сделать мини-игру, стоит задуматься о работе с базой данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как вообще взаимодействовать с переменами из "вне" в функциях

Как обычно - с помощью ключевого слова *global* :

```
@bot.command(pass_context=False)
async def start(ctx):
    global nRound
```